# Set caches_action, :expires_in => dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, action-caching

Every example of `caches_action` I've seen looks like:

```
caches_action, :expires_in => 5.minutes
```

but I'd like to set `expires_in` based on the expiration time of an object used in the action. Is there any way to reference that object when setting `expires_in` since the object in question is based on `params` sent to the action?

I tried using

```
caches_action, :expires_in => Object.find(params[:id])
```

but alas it won't let me reference params there. Suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to use a Proc which can get passed the params of the controller. Here is an example

```
caches_action :show, cache_path: Proc.new {|controller_instance| "some_cache_path_that_is_uniq/#{controller_instance.params[:id]}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main point of action caching is to prevent actions being run every time a new request is coming in. Unless defined explicitly params are not taken into consideration.

If you want to cache based on instances I would suggest doing [Conditional Gets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#conditional-get-support).

Comment: My `params[:id]` is part of the route - something like `/object/:id` - so it gets cached separately since the path is different.